# How to display records not older than one month ago in SQL Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to display results only this month? How can I do it with oracle SQL?

```
select 'Working Equipment' label, count(*)
from LOGS_HISTORY
where MODE__ = 'Working'
group by MODE__ 
having TIME_ < add_months(sysdate, -1)
union all
select 'Standby Equipment' label, count(distinct TAG_IDENTIFIER)
from LOGS_HISTORY
where MODE__ = 'Standby'
```

Please see my code snippet and advise on how can i solve it? Currently I have error because there is no group by in my code

Comment: You need to put a condition into the `where` clause, because it's applied before aggregation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apply the time filter in the `WHERE` clause rather than the `HAVING` clause. If you want it since exactly 1 month before the current instant (including time) then:

```sql
SELECT 'Working Equipment' label,
       count(*)
FROM   LOGS_HISTORY
WHERE  MODE__ = 'Working'
AND    TIME_ >= add_months(sysdate, -1)
union all
SELECT 'Standby Equipment' label,
       count(distinct TAG_IDENTIFIER)
FROM   LOGS_HISTORY
WHERE  MODE__ = 'Standby'
AND    TIME_ >= add_months(sysdate, -1)
```

If you want it in the current month then:

```sql
SELECT 'Working Equipment' label,
       count(*)
FROM   LOGS_HISTORY
WHERE  MODE__ = 'Working'
AND    TIME_ >= TRUNC(sysdate, 'MM')
union all
SELECT 'Standby Equipment' label,
       count(distinct TAG_IDENTIFIER)
FROM   LOGS_HISTORY
WHERE  MODE__ = 'Standby'
AND    TIME_ >= TRUNC(sysdate, 'MM')
```